# What is the proper way of checking a table key existence before using its value?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I want to check if `$table['key']` exists before using it. What is the proper way of doing this?

I've seen a lot of different codes, but I do not know if they are all equivalent and right. Here are a few examples :

```
// 1
if(isset($table['key'])) { ... }

// 2
if(isset($table) and isset($table['key'])) { ... }

// 3
if(isset($table) and array_key_exists('key',$table)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($table['key']))
```

Yes.

```
if (isset($table) and isset($table['key']))
```

That's redundant, there's no advantage to checking both individually.

```
if (isset($table) and array_key_exists('key', $table))
```

Yes, this is also a good method **if** `$table['key']` may hold a `null` value and you're still interested in it. `isset($table['key'])` will return `false` if the value is `null`, even if it exists. You can distinguish between those two cases using `array_key_exists`.

Having said that, `isset($table)` is not something you *should* ever be doing, since you should be in control of declaring `$table` beforehand. In other words, it's inconceivable that `$table` may not exist except in error, so you shouldn't be checking for its existence. Just `if (array_key_exists('key', $table))` should be enough.

Comment: One thing to note is that `isset()` is a language construct and `array_key_exists()` is a function call, if used many times it makes a difference :) also, `isset()` works on objects that implement `ArrayAccess`.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb I personally apply:

1. If the value that corresponds with the key may be `null`:

   1. If `$table` may not exist, use `isset($table) && array_key_exists('key', $table)`.
   2. Otherwise, use `array_key_exists('key', $table)`.
2. In all other cases, use `isset($table['key'])`.

In the cases of 1.1 and 1.2, it's technically possible that `$table` is not an array; in that case you would need to add `is_array($table)` as well ... but if it ever gets this far, something else is wrong imho.